# Does Firebase Auth sign out requires internet connection?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When performing sign out with Firebase Authentication, does it requires internet connection to successfully execute the task? It seems you can use `Firebase.auth.signOut()` even without having internet connection. Does `signOut` method only deletes the session in the local database or cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does signOut method only deletes the session in the local database or cache?

Yes, that's correct.  The state of being "signed in" has nothing to do with the backend and has everything to do with the user token currently in use (specifically, that it is present and has not expired after one hour since the last refresh).

Comment: Thanks a lot, since the token refresh was mention I would like to know if Firebase authentication handles it automatically and internally that is why we usually never encounter it?

Comment: If you are using the Firebase SDK, it is all automatic.

Comment: Will there be any chances that sign out fails?

Comment: Yes, there is a chance that anything can fail, especially anything that requires a network connection. If you have a question  about a specific scenario, please post that separately.